# JMeter - OutSystems - Login Once Controller

Tags: azure, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, outsystems

We are testing an OutSystems application sitting on an Azure infrastructure. When performing a recording all of the requests captured are AJAX calls. And not in the traditional HTML format.

I'm trying to set up a scenario whereby if a transaction fails within the main set of transactions (outside of the login and logout), the script restarts from the beginning of the main transactions. The user shouldn't attempt to login again. The current setting for the thread group is "Action to be taken after Sampler error = Start Next Thread Loop". I have added a Only Once Controller, but when a failure occurs, the script stills attempts another login. I have also added the main transactions within a Runtime Controller. That also doesn't work.

[JMeter Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfueU.png)

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is "Run Once Controller", there is [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) which runs its children only for the 1st iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Demo:

[image]

In the above demo the `Randomly Failing Sampler` is a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which randomly fails in 50% of cases via the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy):

```
if (org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 10) > 5) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
}
```

As you can see in case of failure the virtual user:

1. Goes to the next iteration of the Thread Group
2. Doesn't execute "Login Sampler", it's being run only once, during the 1st iteration of the Thread Group
3. Doesn't execute "Always Successful Sampler" because new iteration is started as soon as failure is detected.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thank you for the explanation. I have added a screenshot of the script structure. Could it be because of the loop controller (loop count = 1) that could be causing this to go back to login steps?

Comment: I got it working now. I had to remove the main transactions out of the loop controller. Thank you for the explanation.